# postgres query not matching negative double precision values

Tags: mysql, postgresql, floating-point, numeric

I'm using psql (9.1.3). I have a table (say) A

A has two columns:

*a_id* : *Integer*

*customer_pay : double precision*

> I have these values in the table.
>
> ```
>  a_id      | customer_pay |
> ```
>
> --------------------+--------------+
>
> ```
>    1733684 |       -264.6 | 
>    1723382 |      -314.84 |
>    1728106 |        50.55 |
>    1741636 |       -264.6 |  (4 rows)
> ```

but when I did

> select a_id from A where  customer_pay = -264.6;

I got **nothing**.

I tried all possible precision variaations like -264.60, -264.00, etc.
This query works accurately for +264.6.
What should I do to select values with negative double precision type.

thaks for the help.

Comment: I ran this in Oracle, seems fine .

Comment: I tried putting "",'',etc.Nothing works for me in postgres.

Comment: If you use `WHERE ROUND(customer_pay) = -264` . Does it work ?

Comment: no. It doesn't. I tried. BETWEEN is working

Comment: If "customer_pay" is some kind of currency, double is the wrong data type. Use decimal instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a_id
from a
where round(customer_pay::numeric, 2) = -264.6
```

[From the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> Calculations with numeric values yield exact results where possible, e.g. addition, subtraction, multiplication. However, calculations on numeric values are very slow compared to the integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the next section.

Answer (score 0):

The data type `DOUBLE PRECISION` is an approximate, inexact data type. I see no reason, someone would ever use it instead of an exact type such as `DECIMAL`.

With approximate data types, no matter what language, you should *never* use `=`. When comparing an inexact data value, always allow for some delta, e.g. `where customer_pay between -264.6000001 and 264.5999999`. This alone should explain why I'd never use them ;-)

Comment: The advantage of floating over numeric is that operations on it are faster.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto: Are they? Can you even measure a difference when working with one or the other in PostgreSQL? If there is any difference, it should be neglectable.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto: Okay, but what takes time in a database is accessing the data (reading indexes and tables, joining, filtering, sorting, aggregating). Whether a column is of decimal or double data type has about zero impact, i.e. it matters little whether a query takes eight seconds or eight seconds plus three nanoseconds.